# A certain sum on the unit disk

Tags: real-analysis

Let us take a sequence of integers $\{n_k\}$ with $n_1 >1$ and $n_{k+1} > 2kn_{k}.$ Set
$$f(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 5^k z^{n_k}.$$

I want to prove that for every $m \geq 1,$if $|z| = 1-1/n_m,$ then there is some constant $C>0$ such that $|f(z)|> C \cdot 5^m.$

My thoughts was to use the reverse triangle inequality, so that 
$$|f(z)|\geq 5^m |1-1/n_m|^{n_m} - |\sum_{k=1, k \neq m} 5^k z^{n_k}|.$$ Then using the triangle inequality this is $\geq$ to 
$$5^m |1-1/n_m|^{n_m} - \sum_{k=1, k \neq m} 5^k |1-1/n_m|^{n_k}.$$ I tried using Bernoulli's inequality, but this gives me nothing. Any hints or solutions would be welcome.

Comment: Is the constant $C$ allowed to depend on $m$, or is it supposed to be independent of $m$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Of course you stated the quantifiers wrong, you really want to show there exists $C$ such that etc.)

If this is true you can probably prove it by grunging through the details in the following. I'm not certain  that it *is* true, depends on a certain sum being less than $1/4-1/e$.

Let $$e_m=(1-1/n_m)^{n_m},$$and note that $$e_m\sim\frac 1e.$$The main term in your $$5^m |1-1/n_m|^{n_m} - \sum_{k=1, k \neq m} 5^k |1-1/n_m|^{n_k}$$is exactly $5^me_m$; we need to show that the sum of the other terms is smaller.

First, $$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} 5^k |1-1/n_m|^{n_k}
\le\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}5^k<\frac14 5^m.$$That's good enough, since $\frac 14<\frac1e$.Now
$$\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty 5^k |1-1/n_m|^{n_k}=5^m\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty 5^{k-m}e_m^{n_k/n_m}.$$Now $n_k/n_m$ is large for $k>m$, so $e_m^{n_k/n_m}$ is small. If you can quantify how small and show that $$\sum_{k=m+1}^\infty 5^{k-m}e_m^{n_k/n_m}\le c<\frac14-\frac1e$$you're done.

Comment: Is it obvious that the constant you will derive in this way will be independent of $m?$ I agree that this seems like a good approach.

Comment: Or wait, I agree that the constant is independent, nevermind.

Comment: $C$ is certainly independent of $m$, the question is whether it comes out positive, heh...